# How to implement print operation using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my view-model i have an command which implements print operation using PrintVisual of PrintDialog class . As i don't have the access to the view i cannot print it .how should tackle this ?

Is there an easier and better approach?

Comment: Just because it's MVVM doesn't mean you have to religiously push every bit of logic into the VM. You'll drive yourself crazy trying to implement "edge cases" such as this, in a pure MVVM fashion. It's perfectly acceptable to continue using events and code-behind, as long as the logic is view-related. I would suggest getting rid of the VM command and use a click event in code-behind instead (assuming you are printing from a button), and save yourself a lot of pain!

Comment: @ andrew stephens . you might be right. I implemented it with events its working fine .Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution would be to pass a service class in that performs the work of printing the grid, showing a dialog, and whatever work is required to get the job done.

In MVVM, most of people use dependency injection to do this. You would create another service with the same interface for your tests to use that wouldn't block execution. The service, in this case, is a view layer service, and should have no dependency back to the viewmodel. The only thing the viewmodel knows is that it has a service interface to call into, and the only thing the service knows about the viewmodel is the interface it implements for this interaction.

I read this Wikipedia article that has helped me in the past:

[SOLID - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it.
I created an event in my viewmodel. Raised the event here whenever i want to print operation.

I defined my listener method in the mainwindow.xaml (this is where i have defined my content presenter , and all the data templates are being assigned to this contentpresenter.content)
In this listener method i am calling the print operation using PrintVisual of PrintDialog Class.

!